# Can not extract text node from xml file

Tags: xml, ant

I am trying to extract text node of an external xml file and assign it to a property, but for now I am struggling just to echo it. Googling I found several approaches to do this, but didn't work to me. Here is what I have tried:

This is the ant script `buld.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
        <target name="info">
            <xmlproperty file="stest-case-1.xml"/>
            <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
            <echo>${processor}</echo>
        </target>
    </project>
```

This is the xml file `test-case-1.xml` (which resides in the same directory as the ant script):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <processor>../../library/saxon-he-9-6-0-7j/saxon9he.jar"</processor>
    <test-case name="test-case-1">
        <object-under-test category="template" name="text-align"/>
        <parameters>
            <input name="text">text</input>
            <input name="min-lenght">8</input>
            <input name="align">left</input>
            <output name="result"/>
        </parameters>
        <criteria>
            <criterion class="equal" to="'text '"/>
        </criteria>
    </test-case>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I get as a result is:

```
    info:
     [echo] Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!
     [echo] ${processor}
```

processor isn't expanded at all.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using the wrong propertysyntax, it works like that =

```
<project>

 <xmlproperty file="test-case-1.xml" collapseattributes="true"/>

 <echo>$${xsl:stylesheet.processor} : ${line.separator}${xsl:stylesheet.processor}</echo>

</project>
```

Simply use `${xsl:stylesheet.processor}` instead of `${processor}`
output :

```
[echo] ${xsl:stylesheet.processor} : 
[echo] ../../library/saxon-he-9-6-0-7j/saxon9he.jar"
```

**Note** the " at the end of the property, seems to be a typo in your test-case-1.xml file.